# Prior value issue on record triggered flow depending on when to run the flow

Tags: visual-workflow, recordtriggeredflow

I am trying to create a record triggered flow that checks when the **Status** picklist field on the **case** object changes from **closed** to **in progress**. When this happens a read-only checkbox field called **reopened** is checked (set to true) and can never be unchecked.

When creating my starting condition for this flow I decided to use a formula and select the option to run the flow **Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements**. But despite working fine on the front end, I get this syntax error on the code that only goes away when I select to run the flow **Every time a record is updated and meets the condition requirements**.

What I would like is for this flow to only fire when the prior value of the status field is "Closed" and when the new value is "In Progress".

So why am I getting this error and will selecting the first open of when to run the flow cause any issues to performance or how many times this flow is checked?

[image]

Comment: There are two types of Trigger flows. One is for quick updates. Is it that you are using?

Comment: Yes, fast field update

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using `PRIORVALUE()` function you cannot use the second option i.e., **Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements**

Using the first option(**Only when a record is updated to meet the condition requirements**) will not trigger the flow multiple times and also will not cause any performance issues because in the formula you are mentioning that the flow should only trigger when the prior value of status is `closed` and present value(While changing) is `In Progress`

Comment: Would this also work when the Status field is changed via another flow?